# ¿Cómo obtener datos desde google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

Ocupo realizar algo similar a lo del siguiente ejemplo
[Google maps: obtener latitud & longitud](http://www.bufa.es/google-maps-latitud-longitud/)

Al momento sólo he podido lograr obtener lat y long ubicando el puntero, pero quiero obtener la dirección de esas coordenadas y viceversa. También que desde un input pueda ubicar en el mapa y obteniendo sus coordenadas.

```
var marker;          //variable del marcador
var coords = {};    //coordenadas obtenidas con la geolocalización

//Funcion principal
initMap = function ()
{

    //usamos la API para geolocalizar el usuario
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          function (position){
            coords =  {
              lng: position.coords.longitude,
              lat: position.coords.latitude
            };
            setMapa(coords);  //pasamos las coordenadas al metodo para crear el mapa


          },function(error){console.log(error);});

}



function setMapa (coords)
{
      //Se crea una nueva instancia del objeto mapa
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      {
        zoom: 13,
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat,coords.lng),

      });

      //Creamos el marcador en el mapa con sus propiedades
      //para nuestro obetivo tenemos que poner el atributo draggable en true
      //position pondremos las mismas coordenas que obtuvimos en la geolocalización
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat,coords.lng),

      });
      //agregamos un evento al marcador junto con la funcion callback al igual que el evento dragend que indica
      //cuando el usuario a soltado el marcador
      marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);

      marker.addListener( 'dragend', function (event)
      {
        //escribimos las coordenadas de la posicion actual del marcador dentro del input #coords

        var latGet = this.getPosition().lat();
        var lngGet = this.getPosition().lng();

        console.log(this.getPosition().lng());

        obtainedCoords(latGet,lngGet);

      });
}

//callback al hacer clic en el marcador lo que hace es quitar y poner la animacion BOUNCE
function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}

// Carga de la libreria de google maps
// Funcion para guardar los datos en bd
function obtainedCoords(latGet,lngGet){
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var lat = latGet;
  var lng = lngGet;

}
```

Si han visto un ejemplo similar y puedan compartirlo, estaría agradecido

Comment: Puedes hacer uso del plugin **jquery-addresspicker** https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker

Comment: Ah claro, no conocia este plugin, veré que tal funciona

Comment: bien jugado con ese plugin. Gracias bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas hacer un geocoding reverso.

Dale un `HTTP GET` a la siguiente URL

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Tienes como resultado:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "277",
               "short_name" : "277",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bedford Avenue",
               "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "11211",
               "short_name" : "11211",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "277 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.714232,
               "lng" : -73.9612889
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7155809802915,
                  "lng" : -73.9599399197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7128830197085,
                  "lng" : -73.96263788029151
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },

   ... Additional results truncated in this example[] ...

   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Mira la propiedad: **"formatted_address"**

Para habilitar esta API, ve a https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start

Comment: Esto me sirvió bastante, gracias

Comment: de nada hermano, estamos para servir, ¡Éxitos con los proyectos! bendiciones :D